# How to use Realm with SwiftUI

Tags: realm, swiftui

I have been trying to figure out how to use Realm with SwiftUI.  The problem is that SwiftUI and Realm both have a List type.  When you import SwiftUI into your Realm model to make the class a BindableObject and try to create a Realm List property there is an error.

Is it possible to use an instance of the Realm object model and make it a BindableObject in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure, it's very simple, use the module identifier as prefix like this :

```
let members = RealmSwift.List<Member>()
```

Now to the second part of your question. It's easy to encapsulate a Realm object (or list, or resultset) in an `BindableObject` :

```swift
final class DBData: BindableObject  {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<DBData, Never>()

    private var notificationTokens: [NotificationToken] = []    
    var posts = Post.all

    init() {
        // Observe changes in the underlying model
        self.notificationTokens.append(posts.observe { _ in
            self.didChange.send(self)
        })

        self.notificationTokens.append(Message.all.observe { _ in
            self.didChange.send(self)
        })
    }
}
```

If you "link" a `DBData` instance to a SwiftUI `View` by either using `@ObjectBinding` or `@EnvironmentObject` the UI will be refreshed and the new value for `posts` (in our example here) will be available each time the underlying realm changes.

Comment: Can you show an example using the latest SwiftUI with Xcode 11 Beta 7?

Comment: This seems to cause a crash any time you delete an object

Answer (score 8):

@JustinMiller I created a ChannelsData class that I use to listen for changes in my chat channels from a Realm collection. I then update the UI by making the ChannelsData an @EnvironmentObject in my view. Here is what works for me in Xcode 11 GM Seed:

```
final class ChannelsData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var channels: [Channel]
    private var channelsToken: NotificationToken?

// Grab channels from Realm, and then activate a Realm token to listen for changes.
init() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    channels = Array(realm.objects(Channel.self)) // Convert Realm results object to Array
    activateChannelsToken()
}

private func activateChannelsToken() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let channels = realm.objects(Channel.self)
    channelsToken = channels.observe { _ in
        // When there is a change, replace the old channels array with a new one.
        self.channels = Array(channels) 
    }
}

deinit {
    channelsToken?.invalidate()
}
```

And then I use an @EnvironmentObject to grab the channels for my view:

```
struct ChannelsContainerView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var channelsData: ChannelsData

    var body: some View {
        List(channelsData.channels.indexed(), id: \.1.id) { index, _ in
            NavigationLink(destination: ChatView()) {
                ChannelRow(channel: self.$channelsData.channels[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the indexed() function in the List. But if you're curious, it comes from Majid's clever approach to creating flexible SwiftUI data storage classes here: https://mecid.github.io/2019/09/04/modeling-app-state-using-store-objects-in-swiftui/

And if you're coming into the view from another view, be sure to add .environmentObject(ChannelsData()) to your view link (and also in your Previews) or it won't work.

Comment: Not sure your solution works - try deleting an item - seems to crash.

Comment: Right! SwiftUI sends changes to View when the @Published property WILL update. When a RealmCollectionChange<Results<T>> notification is received, Results<T> has already updated because it reports “live” changes; Therefore, a fatalError will occur on deletion due to index out of range. I address the solution/problem in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629301/3739895