# How to display Realm Results in SwiftUI List?

Tags: swift, realm, swiftui

I have been able to save data in a Realm database, but have been unable to show the results in a SwiftUI `List`.

I know I have the data and have no problem printing the results in the console.

Is there a way to convert Realm `Result` into a format that can be displayed on a SwiftUI `List`?

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
import Combine

class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}

class SaveDog {
    func saveDog(name: String, age: String) {
        let dog = Dog()
        dog.age  = Int(age)!
        dog.name = name

        // Get the default Realm
        let realm = try! Realm()

     print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

        // Persist your data easily
        try! realm.write {
        realm.add(dog)
        }

        print(dog)
    }
}

class RealmResults: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    func getRealmResults() -> String{
        let realm = try! Realm()
        var results = realm.objects(Dog.self) { didSet 
 {didChange.send(())}}
        print(results)
        return results.first!.name
    }
}

struct dogRow: View {
    var dog = Dog()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(dog.name)
            Text("\(dog.age)")
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var dogName: String = ""
    @State var dogAge: String = ""

    let saveDog = SaveDog()
    @ObjectBinding var savedResults = RealmResults()
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let dogs = Dog()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            TextField($dogName)
            TextField($dogAge)
            Button(action: {
                self.saveDog.saveDog(name: self.dogName, 
                age:self.dogAge)
//                self.savedResults.getRealmResults()
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
            //insert list here to show realm data

            List(0 ..< 5) { 
             item in
                Text(self.savedResults.getRealmResults())
            } //Displays the same thing 5 times
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Some of the code probably may not make sense because I was attempting several approaches to see if anything would work.

This line, for example, will display the result in the List View.

```
return results.first!.name
```

If I just return results, nothing displays in the List Text View.

As I have commented below I will attempt the ForEach approach when I have time.  That looks promising.

Comment: What is the error you're having?

Comment: I can not iterate through the results to display them. I can show .first or .last but can’t show all the results in a list. It seems that it would work with an array of json data but doesn’t know how to handle realm data. I don’t know if the ForEach works either.

Comment: You can directly use a Result or List Realm Object in a very similar fashion to an array. However, without seeing what you've attempted, we would not be able to answer the question (correctly). Also note the issue you are having is that both SwiftUI and Realm have a List object. Marking as duplicate as there is an explanation posted which will provide an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Realm with Swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677291/how-to-use-realm-with-swiftui)

Comment: Also note that if you copy the data from a Results object to something else, array, List etc, it 'breaks' the connection with the parent objects so they will no longer be live updating objects. If you have a listener on results, it will break that as well.

Comment: I was the one that asked the question about using Realm with SwiftUI because of the List object conflict.  That was solved.  The problem with SwiftUI is that is doesn't seem to know how to iterate through and display Realm Results using a SwiftUI List view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The data that you pass in `List` or a `ForEach` must conform to the `Identifiable` protocol.

Either you adopt it in your Realm models or you use `.identified(by:)` method.

---

Even with that, the `View` won't reload if the data changes.

You could wrap `Results` and make it a `BindableObject`, so the view can detect the changes and reload itself:

```swift
class BindableResults<Element>: ObservableObject where Element: RealmSwift.RealmCollectionValue {

    var results: Results<Element>
    private var token: NotificationToken!

    init(results: Results<Element>) {
        self.results = results
        lateInit()
    }

    func lateInit() {
        token = results.observe { [weak self] _ in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        token.invalidate()
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var dogs = BindableResults(results: try! Realm().objects(Dog.self))

    var body: some View {
        List(dogs.results.identified(by: \.name)) { dog in
            DogRow(dog: dog)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While there's some good info here, it doesn't address the question. The OP is using a *SwiftUI List* which this answer doesn't address. Also the real issue is this *I can not iterate through the results to display them* which we can't address until the OP posts the code they've attempted - my guess is it's a SwiftUI/Realm issue but we'll have to see.

Comment: Also note that Realm results conform to standard protocols's so forEach is directly supported. So for example if you have a bunch of dogs stored in Realm and load then in with *let dogResults = realm.objects(DogClass.self)* you can then iterate over the results with *dogResults.forEach { print($0.dog_name)}* which prints their names. So it's unclear why they can't iterate over a Results class.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I will try the forEach approach and report back.  I will also work on getting the code posted later.

Comment: Matteo,  I have not been able to get the .identified(by:) method to work.  I have not tried the Identifiable protocol.  It may take some time to work through that and I may not get to it today.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Jay I meant SwiftUI `ForEach` struct - like `List`, it requires a sequence of `Identifiable` objects.

Comment: @K.Law updated my answer to show how to use `BindableResults` in your specific case - look at how I use the `.identified(by:)` method in the `List`

Comment: Matteo Pacini, you are officially my hero.  It works like a charm.  My only regret is that I didn't ask the question sooner.

Comment: @MatteoPacini - I'm trying to follow this approach to present data from `Realm` in a `SwiftUI List` and everything works except deleting objects from the `List`, I get an `out of bounds` error. The funny thing is that if I change the `List` to a `ForEach` it works fine, you can add, delete and the UI updates. Changing `List(dogs.results, id: \.name) { dog in` to `ForEach(dogs.results, id: \.name) { dog in` works. Any idea how to solve this issue? - Please note that I'm using `id:\.name` instead of `identified(by: \.name)`

Comment: @K.Law - Did you ever tried deleting rows from the `List`? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

This is the most straight forward way of doing it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dog: Results<Dog> = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1)).objects(Dog.self)

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(dog, id: \.name) { i in
        Text(String((i.name)!))
        }
    }
}
```

...That's it, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

I have created a generic solution to display and add/delete for any `Results<T>`. By default, `Results<T>` is "live". SwiftUI sends changes to View when the `@Published` property **WILL** update. When a `RealmCollectionChange<Results<T>>` notification is received, `Results<T>` has already updated; Therefore, a `fatalError` will occur on deletion due to index out of range. Instead, I use a "live" `Results<T>` for tracking changes and a "frozen" `Results<T>` for use with the View. A full working example, including how to use a generic `View` with `RealmViewModel<T>` (shown below), can be found here: [SwiftUI+Realm](https://github.com/shawnynicole/SwiftUI-Realm). The `enum Status` is used to display a `ProgressView`, "No records found", etc., when applicable, as shown in the project. Also, note that the "frozen" `Results<T>` is used when needing a count or single object. When deleting, the `IndexSet` by `onDelete` is going to return a position from the "frozen" `Results<T>` so it checks that the object still existing in the "live" `Results<T>`.

```
class RealmViewModel<T: RealmSwift.Object>: ObservableObject, Verbose where T: Identifiable {

typealias Element = T

enum Status {
    // Display ProgressView
    case fetching
    // Display "No records found."
    case empty
    // Display results
    case results
    // Display error
    case error(Swift.Error)
    
    enum _Error: String, Swift.Error {
        case fetchNotCalled = "System Error."
    }
}

init() {
    fetch()
}

deinit {
    token?.invalidate()
}

@Published private(set) var status: Status = .error(Status._Error.fetchNotCalled)

// Frozen results: Used for View

@Published private(set) var results: Results<Element>?

// Live results: Used for NotificationToken

private var __results: Results<Element>?

private var token: NotificationToken?

private func notification(_ change: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Element>>) {
    switch change {
        case .error(let error):
            verbose(error)
            self.__results = nil
            self.results = nil
            self.token = nil
            self.status = .error(error)
        case .initial(let results):
            verbose("count:", results.count)
            //self.results = results.freeze()
            //self.status = results.count == 0 ? .empty : .results
        case .update(let results, let deletes, let inserts, let updates):
            verbose("results:", results.count, "deletes:", deletes, "inserts:", inserts, "updates:", updates)
            self.results = results.freeze()
            self.status = results.count == 0 ? .empty : .results
    }
}

var count: Int { results?.count ?? 0 }

subscript(_ i: Int) -> Element? { results?[i] }

func fetch() {
    
    status = .fetching
    
    //Realm.asyncOpen(callback: asyncOpen(_:_:))
    
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(Element.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id")
        self.__results = results
        self.results = results.freeze()
        self.token = self.__results?.observe(notification)
        
        status = results.count == 0 ? .empty : .results
        
    } catch {
        verbose(error)
        
        self.__results = nil
        self.results = nil
        self.token = nil
        
        status = .error(error)
    }
}

func insert(_ data: Element) throws {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write({
        realm.add(data)
    })
}

func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) throws {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write({
        
        offsets.forEach { (i) in
            guard let id = results?[i].id else { return }
            guard let data = __results?.first(where: { $0.id == id }) else { return }
            realm.delete(data)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for posting this - do you know if the new frozen() collections address this problem properly now ?  I assume the 5.2.0 sample code no longer has issues with deletes and handles the live updates in a safe manner.

Comment: The frozen collection does not necessarily address the problem directly. A frozen collection is basically a copy of the collection at that given time and does not receive updates when the realm changes. To track and apply changes, you must track a live collection and manually keep your frozen collection up to date. Keeping a frozen and live collection separately allows you to have control over when you send the changes to the View. At this time, I have not been able to find any official documentation or code from Realm demonstrating how to otherwise implement SwiftUI and Realm together.

Comment: I am using the frozen collection as per their example and it live updates (and by that I mean items added/removed from the list) - I think it should work because the view is getting the change notifications and is then using a new 'frozen' collection to compare against the old frozen collection so it works without throwing exceptions.  I guess where it won't work is if objects in the collection have properties changed these property changes won't get shown in the view.

Comment: It appears that you are saying your frozen collection is receiving live updates. A frozen collection should not be receiving updates, and I did not have that issue when using a frozen collection. Can you post an example of that happening? Regarding property updates, the change notification sends 3 types of changes: deletes, inserts, and updates. So when a property changes, you will receive an array of indices for the objects that had updates. If you want to track which properties changed, you will need to have a notification token for each object. I also demonstrate that in my full demo.

Comment: Yes my view is getting updated automatically when new items are added to the database. I'll past the code as another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using the new Realm frozen() collections.  While this is early days the UI is updated automatically when 'assets' get added to the database. In this example they are being added from an NSOperation thread, which should be a background thread.

In this example the sidebar lists different property groups based on the distinct values in the database - note that you may wish to implement this in a more robust manner - but as a quick POC this works fine. See image below.

```
struct CategoryBrowserView: View {
    @ObservedObject var assets: RealmSwift.List<Asset> = FileController.shared.assets
    @ObservedObject var model = ModelController.shared
    
    @State private var searchTerm: String = ""
    @State var isEventsShowing: Bool = false
    @State var isProjectsShowing: Bool = false
    @State var isLocationsShowing: Bool = false
    
    var projects: Results<Asset> {
        return assets.sorted(byKeyPath: "project").distinct(by: ["project"])
    }
    var events: Results<Asset> {
        return assets.sorted(byKeyPath: "event").distinct(by: ["event"])
    }
    var locations: Results<Asset> {
        return assets.sorted(byKeyPath: "location").distinct(by: ["location"])
    }
    @State var status: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                // Projects
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isProjectsShowing) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment:.trailing, spacing: 4) {
                        
                        ForEach(filteredProjectsCollection().freeze()) { asset in
                            HStack {
                                    Text(asset.project)
                                    Spacer()
                                Image(systemName: self.model.selectedProjects.contains(asset.project) ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                                    .onTapGesture { self.model.addProject(project: asset.project) }
                            }
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack(alignment:.center) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.2")
                        Text("Projects").font(.system(.title3))
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding([.top, .bottom], 8).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                
                // Events
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isEventsShowing) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment:.trailing, spacing: 4) {
                        
                        ForEach(filteredEventsCollection().freeze()) { asset in
                            HStack {
                             Text(asset.event)
                                Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: self.model.selectedEvents.contains(asset.event) ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                                .onTapGesture { self.model.addEvent(event: asset.event) }
                            }
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack(alignment:.center) {
                        Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        Text("Events").font(.system(.title3))
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding([.top, .bottom], 8).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                
                // Locations
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isLocationsShowing) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment:.trailing, spacing: 4) {
                        
                        ForEach(filteredLocationCollection().freeze()) { asset in
                            HStack {
                             Text(asset.location)
                                Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: self.model.selectedLocations.contains(asset.location) ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                                .onTapGesture { self.model.addLocation(location: asset.location) }
                            }
                        }
                    }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    
                } label: {
                    HStack(alignment:.center) {
                        Image(systemName: "flag")
                        Text("Locations").font(.system(.title3))
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding([.top, .bottom], 8).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                
            }.padding(.all, 10)
            .background(Color(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor))
        }
            SearchBar(text: self.$searchTerm)
                .frame(height: 30, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    
    func filteredProjectsCollection() -> AnyRealmCollection<Asset> {
        if self.searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.projects)
        } else {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.projects.filter("project CONTAINS[c] %@ || event CONTAINS[c] %@ || location CONTAINS[c] %@ || tags CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm))
        }
    }
    func filteredEventsCollection() -> AnyRealmCollection<Asset> {
        if self.searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.events)
        } else {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.events.filter("project CONTAINS[c] %@ || event CONTAINS[c] %@ || location CONTAINS[c] %@ || tags CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm))
        }
    }
    func filteredLocationCollection() -> AnyRealmCollection<Asset> {
        if self.searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.locations)
        } else {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.locations.filter("project CONTAINS[c] %@ || event CONTAINS[c] %@ || location CONTAINS[c] %@ || tags CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm))
        }
    }
    func filteredCollection() -> AnyRealmCollection<Asset> {
        if self.searchTerm.isEmpty {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.assets)
        } else {
            return AnyRealmCollection(self.assets.filter("project CONTAINS[c] %@ || event CONTAINS[c] %@ || location CONTAINS[c] %@ || tags CONTAINS[c] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm))
        }
    }
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        if let realm = assets.realm {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(assets[offsets.first!])
            }
        } else {
            assets.remove(at: offsets.first!)
        }
    }
    
}

struct CategoryBrowserView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoryBrowserView()
    }
}

struct CheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        return HStack {
            configuration.label
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                .onTapGesture { configuration.isOn.toggle() }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]