# How to refresh swiftUI view automatically after Core Data updating in background?

Tags: swift, core-data, background, swiftui

How to refresh swiftUI view automatically after Core Data updating in background, without onAppear method being called?

```
struct Page1: View {

@FetchRequest(entity: Word.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
var wordsFromCoreData: FetchedResults<Word>

@State var isPresenting = false


var body: some View {

    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: Page2()){
                Text("Add")

            }
            List(wordsFromCoreData, id: \.self){item in

                WordRowView(word:item)

            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("English Words"))
        }
    }
}
}
```

Yes, I think `@FetchRequest` will help me **reload** the data automaticly after my Page1 **appear**

But, If I use `NavigationLink` or `.sheet` to get to Page2, swift won't call onAppear I think.

So, If I go to Page2, do some Core Data thing like fetching image from Internet, then I go back to Page1, it never show the data, but the data has actually existed in My Core Data. So, it means Page1 doesn't refresh the data in this situation.

Another situation works fine, for example, I set Page2 as another `TabView` instead of `NavigationLink(A Detail View)`, when I go back to Page1, the view has been refreshed.

But I prefer `NavigationLink` to get my work done. So, Is There any way to refresh swiftUI view automatically after Core Data updating in background?

Comment: I have the same problem.  The detail page does not auto refresh if I change the core data in detail page.   Any solution you have already?

Comment: @Emmy I change CoreData to Realm , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720441/how-to-display-realm-results-in-swiftui-list This solution works for Realm, I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData have built in Notifications.

Look this article for [details](https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/core-data-notifications-with-swift-acc8232a674e).

In your Views you can use `.onReceive` modificator to receive this notifications and update View.