# How to delete data from SwiftUI List and Realm

Tags: ios, realm, swiftui, swiftui-list

The following code properly displays all of the 'Users' from `Realm` database in a SwiftUI `List`. My issue is deleting records when I swipe a row.

When I swipe a row and tap the delete button, I immediately get an `uncaught exception` error, the `List` does not update but I know the right item gets deleted from the `Realm` database since the next time I run the app the selected record doesn't show up.

Here is my code.

### SwiftUI Code

```
import RealmSwift

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var allUsers: Results<User> = realm.objects(User.self)

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Second Tab")
            List{
                ForEach(allUsers, id:\.self) { user in
                    HStack{
                        Text(user.name)
                        Text("\(user.age)")
                    }
                }.onDelete(perform: deleteRow)
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteRow(with indexSet: IndexSet){
        indexSet.forEach ({ index in
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(self.allUsers[index])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Realm Model

```
import RealmSwift

class User:Object{
    @objc dynamic var name:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var age:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    @objc dynamic var userID = UUID().uuidString
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

### ERROR

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 4 is out of bounds (must be less than 4).'

Of course, the `4` changes depending on how many items are in the `Realm` database, in this case, I had 5 records when I swiped and tapped the delete button.

My expectation was that the `List` was going to update every time the `allUsers` @State variable changes, I know my issue is not fully understanding how binding works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on which exact operation, line, you get this exception?

Comment: The error points to the AppDelegate - `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: The first issue is that data passed in List or a ForEach must conform to the Identifiable protocol. Also, as it sits Realm is not a super great fit for SwiftUI due to the nature of Results objects - you're probably going to want to lean on notifications to handle UI updates for the time being. Once Realm has Frozen Objects, it will be easier to implement Realm functionality.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly what you are saying is that as of right now, Realm and SwiftUI don't play well together? Learn notification on the Realm side or SwiftUI? Thank you for pointing out the fact that data passed in List or a ForEach must conform to the Identifiable protocol.

Comment: That has been our experience to date. It's not really a Realm 'issue' as Results are working as intended - it's the interaction with the nature of SwiftUI. There are a number of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brealm%5DswiftUI) here on SO but no actual answers that are not workarounds - most of them tie back to leveraging notifications.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common bug when working with Realm. It happens in ''traditional'' view controllers too.

The only solid solution I found, and it has considerably improved applications stability is to always use interface items instead of realm object.

Moreover, in real life, we need to do some processes, load avatar images from server, add some check boxes, selections or whatever, and we often don't need all properties of objects to be displayed. Somehow, it's a MVVM approach.

By the way, you can call `realm.write` before the loop, not sure, but I think it's good to minimise context switching.

Using this technique, either with SwiftUI or UIViewControllers, will solve RLM crashes for good.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    struct UserItem: Hashable {
        var id: String
        var name: String
        var age: Int
    }

    private var allUsers: Results<User> = realm.objects(User.self)

    @State private var userItems: [UserItem] = []
    
    func updateItems() {
        userItems = allUsers.map {
            UserItem(id: $0.userID, name: $0.name, age: $0.age)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second Tab")
            List{
                ForEach(userItems, id:\.self) { user in
                    HStack{
                        Text(user.name)
                        Text("\(user.age)")
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteRow)
                
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            updateItems()
        }
    }

    private func deleteRow(with indexSet: IndexSet){
        try! realm.write {
            indexSet.forEach {
                realm.delete(self.allUsers[$0])
            }
        }
        updateItems()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> My expectation was that the List was going to update every time the
>   allUsers @State variable changes

It is correct, but state was not changed... The following should work

```
private func deleteRow(with indexSet: IndexSet){
    indexSet.forEach ({ index in
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(self.allUsers[index])
        }
    })
    self.allUsers = realm.objects(User.self)     // << refetch !!
}
```

Note: the below is just assigning *initial* state value

```
@State private var allUsers: Results<User> = realm.objects(User.self)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, re-fetching after deleting the record from Realm as you suggest doesn't work, I get the same exact error.

Comment: @fs_tigre Unfortunately `assigning initial state value` isn't correct due to the nature of Results objects. They are live updating - that means a realm Results object maintains a live connection to it's underlying objects, if an object is added to Realm, the results will include that object. if an object is deleted, the object will no longer be included in those Results. Results objects can be observed for changes and then action can be taken if an object is added, modified or removed. I am pretty sure `@State` is not the right thing here.

Comment: Any idea where can I find information on how to restructure my code?

Comment: @fs_tigre Sometimes simpler is better so I would just make the allUsers results a class var and then add an observer to that var. Within the observer block, just refresh the tableView when something changes. If you don't need animated UI elements in your tableView, that will do it. If you do, then you can leverage the observer closure to control the tableView updates at a more fine-grained row level.

Comment: Hmm, but this is `SwiftUI` and I'm not sure how to refresh/reload a `List`. This whole new concept of `SwiftUI` is driving me nuts. I have tried some other different approaches and I have been getting the same issue, for instance I tried this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720441/how-to-display-realm-results-in-swiftui-list I get the same crash.

Comment: @fs_tigre, the more I think about this the more tend to the mind that the reason is somewhere else... If the crash was originated by SwiftUI it would be some iOS originated thing... like UIKit internals exception, or swift library... but you declare that it is RLMException and this is realm internal exception, while by provided code everything should be correct as delete is performed within write transaction... and result should update, as designed & documented, immediately.

Comment: @Asperi - I have been reading some other related threads and it looks like I’m not the only one having issues deleting rows, even using notifications and bindable objects.  FYI the code I posted in my original post is all the code I have in the project, except for a global variable `let realm = try! Realm()` in the `AppDelegate.swift` which is right above/before `@UIApplicationMain`.  I refuse to think that there is no current solution to integrate Realm with SwiftUI :-(.

Comment: I suspect the issue is because SwiftUI is referencing a deleted Realm object and realm throws an exception.  So you can't ever directly use realm objects or collections.  I use a wrapper for realm objects and realm collections so realm objects are never access directly by SwiftUI (or NSOutlineView for that matter!).

Comment: WRT reloading/refreshing the SwiftUI list - you can't - it doesn't work that way - you MUST use an observable object and when that object posts a change notification SwiftUI will refresh - but even it's refresh is smart - it will only update the changes - and therein lies the problem - the object you deleted can't be accessed once it's deleted or realm throws an exception - and SwiftUI needs to check the object to see if it is in the new list - at least that is my understanding - I found a post somewhere where this is explained in more detail.

Comment: here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160790/index-out-of-bounds-when-using-realm-with-swiftui

Comment: See my answer. The only working solution I ever found. It also have the advantage of decoupling the view from the database layer. So Realm can be replaced by another tech at low cost.

Comment: About the `@State` keyword, it defines the source of truth for the data. So it should not be used to point to an external datasource. The only valid state for a `@State` property is defined by the view itself. In the code in your question, you link the view state to an external object. The view is the source of truth, since it is it who displays objects ( they may be filtered for example, and not be the original list ) and decides to delete objects if the user swipes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to create a additional 'var isdeleted = false' to your struct, Do it like this:

```
struct UserItem: Hashable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var isdeleted = false //<== THIS IS NEW

}
```

Then your delete function only sets this value 'isdeleted' to true
Now you only have to add a filter (show all where 'isdeleted = false') to your view function

```
realm.objects(Task.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "isdeleted == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false)))
```

If you want to you can then create another function that cleans up your realm Database and deletes all Entries with 'isdeleted = true'

Comment: While answers are appreciated, whats being described here is a *soft delete*. It's not related to the issue in the question though. The OP doesn't want to soft delete, and then clean up the database later; they want to delete the object from Realm, and have the UI updated to reflect that. The actual issue was using the wrong property type so their code was attempting to reference an object that no longer exists. The correct solution would be to use [ObservedResults](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/react-to-changes/#observe-query-results) instead of the State var.

Comment: It might be helpful to use inline code instead of actual quotes here so that the code stands out visually