# SwiftUI: Implement Rating view with database connection

Tags: ios, swift, database, rest, swiftui

In my App I want the user to rate a movie. Movies are loaded from a REST-Interface, the rating should be stored locally. Problem is that I don't know how to persist the new rating of a user.

I can load the rating from my database and change the value in the MovieRow but I do not know how to get the callback for saving the changed rating.

Here is what I have:

```
struct RatingView: View {

    @Binding var rating: Int

    var maximumRating = 5
    var offImage: Image?
    var onImage = Image(systemName: "star.fill")
    var offColor = Color.gray
    var onColor = Color.yellow

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            ForEach(1..<maximumRating + 1) { number in
                self.image(for: number)
                    .foregroundColor(number > self.rating ? self.offColor : self.onColor)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.rating = number
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    func image(for number: Int) -> Image {
        if number > rating {
            return offImage ?? onImage
        } else {
            return onImage
        }
    }
}

struct MovieRow: SwiftUI.View {

    let movie: Movie
    @State var ownRating: Int

    var body: some SwiftUI.View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .bottom)) {
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .trailing, vertical: .top
            )) {
                KFImage(movie.fullPosterURL)
                    .cancelOnDisappear(true)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(height: 250)
                RatingView(rating: $ownRating)
                    .padding([.top, .trailing], 20.0)
            }
            Text(movie.title)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.all)
                .background(Color(.darkGray)
                    .opacity(0.5))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct MovieListView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(viewModel.movies) { movie in
                MovieRow(movie: movie, ownRating: self.viewModel.ratingForMovieId(id: movie.id))
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
        }
    }
}

class MovieViewModel: ObservableObject{

    private let provider: NetworkManager?
    private let ratingModel = RatingModel()

    @Published var movies = [Movie]()

    init(provider: NetworkManager? = NetworkManager(), movies: [Movie] = []) {
        self.provider = provider
        self.movies = movies

        loadNewMovies()
    }

    func loadNewMovies(){
         provider?.getNewMovies(page: 1) {[weak self] movies in
                   print("\(movies.count) new movies loaded")
                   self?.movies.removeAll()
            self?.movies.append(contentsOf: movies)}
    }

    func ratingForMovieId(id: Int)->Int{
        return ratingModel.ratingForMovieId(movieId: id)
    }
}

class RatingModel{

    let realm = try! Realm()

    func ratingForMovieId(movieId: Int)->Int{

        let result = realm.objects(MovieRating.self).filter("movieId = %@", movieId)

        guard let movieRating = result.first else{
            return 0
        }
        return movieRating.rating
    }

    func updateRating(movieId: Int, rating: Int){

        try! realm.write {
            realm.create(MovieRating.self, value: ["movieId": movieId, "rating": rating], update: .modified)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a specific answer to this you would have to provide more information about the database/ViewModel/REST-Interface

Some things that might address your issue `@State var ownRating: Int` to `@Binding var ownRating: Int`. `State` is meant to be used just within a view and should be declared `private`, `Binding` will pass on the connection with the `ViewModel`

When `onTapGesture` is activated reference your `ViewModel` and use the REST-Interface's pre-established save()/update() from there.

You might have to pass the whole `Movie` object or an `id` variable to `RatingView` if your save/update method needs the object/id to persist.

The UI refreshing when a rating is changed depends on a "ping" or "notification" that something has happened. SwiftUI and it tutorials heavily rely on CoreData for that part.

I am not familiar with Realm but this is what I could gather about it. `Realm` has `NotificationTokens` that will provide the required Notification for the SwiftUI update in an observable object.

Getting objects for a ListView - [How to use Realm with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677291/how-to-use-realm-with-swiftui)

Getting started guide - https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Tutorial with a UITableView query code should be what you need - https://academy.realm.io/posts/meetup-jp-simard-mastering-realm-notifications/

Troubleshooting a ListView with `observed` Realm objects - [Index out of bounds when using Realm with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160790/index-out-of-bounds-when-using-realm-with-swiftui)

Creating Realm Data Models and Saving - https://learnappmaking.com/realm-database-swift-getting-started/

You should create an ObservableObject with the standard CRUD methods.

`Movie` object from the UI -> `ViewModel.create(newMovie: Movie)` in Realm -> Notify/Save the `@Published var movies` with the new query from Realm

At `ViewModel` `init()` Retrieve `[Movie]` from `Realm` -> setup `NotifiationToken` to `observe` and `@Published var movies` with the new query from Realm

Updated Movie.rating from the UI -> ViewModel.update(updatedMovie) in Realm-> Notify/update `@Published var movies` with the new query from Realm

Delete works the same way as the others.

There are many different ways on how to persist and this is certainly not the most efficient because it retrieves the whole query every time but it should get you started. The NotificationToken seems to support updates down to the letter with the correct `NotificationToken.observer`.

Specifically to your code. When the user `onTapGesture`the new rating you should reference `viewModel.update(updatedMovie: updatedMovie)` then the view will change when it gets a new list of `movies` from the `NotificationToken`.

Comment: I added my ViewModel and RatingModel. Main problem is to get a ping that the value changed in the UI. And I store the rating separately. Not inside a movie object. This was generated from JSON structure of my web interface.

Comment: I added some information to my answer. I am not familiar with Realm so I can't give you exact code but this should get you looking in the right direction.

Comment: And what if we forget Realm for a moment and replace it with a REST interface? The core problem ist that I have a state mutation inside my view hierarchy and I want to be notified about it in my view model without passing in a reference. Is there no SwiftUI feature to pass this state upwards?

Comment: The only way to persist in a "built-in" way is through CoreData.

I did this video a few days ago for somebody else. It implements a FetchedResultsController with SwiftUI. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U-4Zon6dbE You can see how to create/save an object at beginning, in the YourModelExt class addSample(). Whatever REST-Interface that you use will have to have some kind of notification system to tell the State/ObservedObject that the View/list/object needs updating.

Comment: If you use CoreData after the onTapGesture you would use your managedObjectContenxt.save(). The FetchResultsController manages the notifications.