# SwiftUI List from Realm DB

Tags: ios, realm, swiftui, swiftui-list, realm-list

How do I create a List from a Realm DB?

I really struggle with the *id thing*. I have no clue how to implement it correctly.

This is my ViewController:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct MyCarsView: View {

     let realm = try! Realm()
     var cars: Results<Car>?

    var body: some View {

        List(cars, id: \.id) { car in
            MyCarsRow(brand: car.brand, model: car.model, image: Image(car.image))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview of the Row]

And this my RealmStruct:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Car: Object {
    let id = UUID()
    @objc dynamic var brand: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var model: String = ""

    @objc dynamic var image: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var dateSaved: Date = Date()
}
```

Comment: What is Result Here? Have you tried List<Car> ?

Comment: @MohitMangla i will get this error  _Generic type 'List' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)_ `var cars: List<Car>?`

Comment: oh its `RealmSwift.List<Car>?` @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/56685263/13175606

Comment: Yes... I am taking about List of RealmSwift.

Comment: thanks! Any Idee why I get nil?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't really do anything realm-wise. If you want to populate a results object, you need to tell realm to do that e.g. `let results = realm.objects(Car.self)` which will retrieve all of the Car objects and populate the results with them.  This `var cars: Results<Car>?` will just bed nil because it's not been populated. I would suggest going through the Realm [Getting Started guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) as it covers a LOT of details about how to use Realm.

Comment: thanks for the tipp @Jay, Unfortunately it will return the following error _Cannot use instance member 'realm' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available_

Comment: Yup, that's correct. You need to follow the MVC pattern. Your controller will contain a datasource which backs your view. That datasource needs to be populated first, and then the view pulls it's data to be displayed from that dataSource. You need to put the code to populate your dataSource from realm in the correct spot. Please update your question with current code and we'll take a look and also take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)